# Square-free factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb C$, i.e. $p(x)=\prod_{k=1}^m(x-x_k)^{n_k}$ with $n_k\in\mathbb N$, $x_k\in\mathbb C$ and $x_k\neq x_j$ if $k\neq j$. In case that $n_k>1$ for some $k$, we can study the map
$$ \prod_{k=1}^m(x-x_k)^{n_k}\longmapsto \prod_{k=1}^m(x-x_k)$$
that deletes the multiple roots and produces a separable polynomial. I was wondering if there is a conceptual description of this map, be it algebraic or analytic. Many thanks for any hints!

Comment: the degree is not $m$

Comment: by the way, you can express this map as $p(x)/(p(x),p'(x))$

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Exodd !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned by Exodd above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733303/square-free-factorization#comment7675226_3733303), a concrete expression for the this map would be $p\mapsto p/gcd(p,p')$, since the derivative of the polynomial $p$ over an algebraically closed field with repeated roots looks like $p'=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_k)Q$, where $Q$ has none of the $a_i$'s as its roots. A conceptual description could be the following: assuming you know what they are, you could think of this map as taking the characteristic polynomial of some class of similar matrices to its minimal one.